# Redirect user based on sign_in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to redirect a user based on a params they used to sign_in but I dont see a way to.

User signs in from `/users/sign_in/?demo=car`

**Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController**

```
def create
 super
 # get the params
 if params[:demo] == car
  # redirect_to where_ever
 end
end
```

Obviously that would not work.

The correct redirect:

**ApplicationController < ActionController::Base**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 # I must have params[:demo] here. How?
 if params[:demo] == car
  # go elsewhere
 else
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
 end
end
```

A very long way would to update the user's column with the params then in `after_sign_in_path_for` I check the `current_user` column for the params then redirect. If user came from just the original url the I update the column to `""`. Waste of time, right?

Comment: You can add a hidden input to your login form and fill its value with `params[:demo]`. After submitting the form (logging in), the value will be accessible from `params`.

Comment: I still need to have that params after the user is logged in. I think I may need to update the user model to do what I want.

Comment: I've presented the way to forward the parameter into `after_sign_in_path_for` method. You can then save it in the database or store it in the session. It depends on your case ;)

Comment: Hi. I was getting too many errors and all I wanted was something simple. I've posted my solution and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I had to copy the code from the Devise gem, [create](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), into mine.

```
def create
  # Do not use super!
  url = params[:redir]
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

  if url
    return # my destination
  end

  # Continue if no param
  set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

 # Alternatively, I could have pass after_sign_in_path_for another param, url
 # then get it in ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

**Views:**

```
# /users/sessions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name, redir: params[:redirect_uri])) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score -1):

make a before action to set a @redir. If you need to persist beetwen page redirects, store in your session

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   before_action :set_redir, if: -> { params[:redir].present? }

   def set_redir
     @redir = CGI.unescape(params[:redir])
     session[:redir] = @redir
   end

   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     session[:redir] || request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
   end

 end
```

Session form

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name, redir: CGI.escape("http://someurl")), html: {role: 'form'}) do |f|   %>
```